# How to apply shift operation in C++?

Tags: c++

I have written the following code.

```
int main() {
int i = 3;
int right = ((1 << i));
cout << right << endl;
system("pause");
}
```

from what i understand, shouldnt the value of right be 6? because 3 in binary is 011 and that one shifted left is 110 which is 6. However the output that i am getting is 8. Why is that?

Comment: you are looking for `i << 1` (11 --> 110).. and not `1 << i` (1 --> 1000)

Comment: http://www.miniwebtool.com/bitwise-calculator/bit-shift/?data_type=2&number=011&place=1&operator=Shift+Left

Comment: Oh, so what is this operation doing?

Comment: This is shifting the value 1 (0001 in binary) to the left `i` bits, giving you 8 (1000 in binary). Therefore `1` corresponds to “Number” and `i` corresponds to “The number of bits to shift” in your link.

Comment: This shifts your value `i` bits to the left and adds 0 to the empty places. `1<<3` changes 1 to 1000 which is 8 in decimal.

Comment: I have another question? when we write int number = 100? In memory how many bits are allocated for this? Like what is the largest number that i can initialize in binary form to an integer?

Answer (score 4):

`i << n` , multiplies `i` with 2<sup>n</sup>

You are getting 8 as 
1 << 3 = 1 * 2<sup>3</sup>

```
1 << 0 = 000...0000001 = 1
1 << 1 = 000...0000010 = 2
1 << 2 = 000...0000100 = 4
1 << 3 = 000...0001000 = 8
```

Comment: You have typos 1 << 1 is not 4 nor is it 8 (i.e., your last 2 examples).